# Why does the 'if' condition here works?

Tags: javascript

The code here check for prime numbers from 2 to n:

```
<script>
function showPrimes(n) {

  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (!isPrime(i)) continue;

    alert(i);  // a prime
  }
}

function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if ( n % i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

</script>
```

But I don't understand why it works for number 2 and return false when both n and i equal to 2 while it doesn't happen with other prime numbers. I am new to javascript(and programming in general) and from what I understood this code take the i from the first iteration in the first loop(on the "showPrimes" function) and put it on "isPrime" function as a parameter and in that function it becomes the "n" in the 'if' condition and it checks if there is a remainder when it gets divided by the i from the loop of "isPrime" so (n % i == 0) should be (2 % 2 == 0) in the first iteration, Is that right? if so why does it works just like it work for other prime numbers which clearly become false unlike (2 % 2 == 0) which is true...

What I am missing here?. Sorry if this is an obvious/stupid question, it is the first time I am learning anything related to programming.

Comment: Because `i >= n` (`2 >= 2`), so that loop is never entered.

Comment: I recommend you to use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: well, `n` is not `10` in the `isPrime` function, maybe that is your confusion? It would actually be the `i` from the `showPrimes` function instead?

Comment: so if the parameter doesn't fit the condition of the loop it just skip on the loop to the next lines of code?

Comment: "But I don't understand why it works for number 2..." Why what works? "...while it doesn't happen with other prime numbers" What doesn't happen? Please be more specific. Especially be more careful with pronouns such as "it" when it is difficult to determine what you are referring to.

Comment: the " showPrimes(10);" was something I added when I checked it on my brackets software. I accidentally copy/past it with the rest of the code.

Comment: Also, it is often useful to step through code line by line to understand how it works. The tips described in [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) are helpful for doing this as much as they are for debugging to find an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
```

When n=2; i=2; The above loop will not be entered.